# sequelize redux map doesn't working when I use findAndCountAll

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, sequelize.js

when I use findAll like this:

```
try{
    const brands = await Brand.findAll({});
    res.status(200).json(brands);

}catch(err){
    console.error(err);
}
```

redux tree likes:

```
brand: {
list: [
  {
    id: 1,
    useYn: 'Y',
    createdAt: '2021-11-30T08:12:54.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-11-30T08:12:54.000Z'
  },
```

so I can use the List by 'useSelector((state) => state.brand.list);'

but when I use findAndCountAll:

```
try{
    const brands = await Brand.findAndCountAll({});
    res.status(200).json(brands);

}catch(err){
    console.error(err);
}
```

It comes:

```
 brand: {
list: {
  count: 20,
  rows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      useYn: 'Y',
      createdAt: '2021-11-30T08:12:54.000Z',
      updatedAt: '2021-11-30T08:12:54.000Z'
    },
```

so I've tried

```
const brandList = useSelector((state) => state.brand.list);
brandList.rows.map(()...
```

and
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
occur!

but I can access and print count! (by brandList.count)

and console:
{count: 20, rows: Array(20)}
count: 20
rows: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}

saying 'rows' is Array.....

what's wrong? I'm really stuck

Comment: I think your store is badly initialize, so before you get the result of your query state.brand.list doesn't exist (that's why the cannot read property of undefined). You can change the initialize of your state or test if the brandList.rows is undefined before using it.

Comment: @Nicolas Menettrier Thanks! I just added a condition and It's working... I think It's because It tried render before being allocated.